# How to switch users for Python CGI Programming?

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, apache2, cgi

I have an HTML form which is handled by a Python script using CGI programming. From my Python script, I want to switch users from `apache2` to `monkey`. The reason is because I'm using `os.system` to run another script from within my Python script.

The Python script works fine but I keep getting Permission errors when executing this command: `os.system('python other_script.py')`. What I realize is that when I am running the HTML form, I am `apache2` instead of `monkey`. I'd like to know how to switch users (as `monkey` not `root`) while executing the Python script.

Here is what my Python script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -W

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 
import pwd
import grp
import sys
import os

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'

os.system('python other_script.py')     # getting permission errors here
```

Comment: If you're using `os.system`, you can use the `su` or `sudo` commands with the `-u` argument.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo When I use `os.system("echo pwd| sudo -u monkey -S 'python other_script.py' ")`, I get this error: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: @Alias does your account have a password?

Comment: @jakekimds the password is `pwd` for `monkey` but I don't know the password for `apache2`. Any idea where I can find out?